# What websites can I use to get games in my schools IPad?

Tags: gmail

I want to download games in school iPad but I don’t have the AppStore. What are some websites that I can use?

Comment: The only way to load an app on an IOS device is via the App Store.

Comment: Any of the sites they haven’t blocked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer you can’t download games outside of the AppStore, but, you can search on google for `html games`

**NOT RECOMMENDED, doing this is on your own responsibilities**

And the long answer, you can download games from the Internet through Safari, but it’s (almost) only games that are breaking the law or for other reason isn’t allowed in the AppStore, they may contain malware/viruses, content kids shouldn’t watch or they may even steal your data.